# Getting "null or not an object" error when validating form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, null

I'm using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var emailRule = /^[_\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)*(\.[\D]{2,3})$/;

    if (emailRule.test(document.forms[0].email.value))
        window.alert("That was a valid email address");
    else
        window.alert("That was not a valid email address");
</script>
```

to validate this:

```
<form action="">
    <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/></p>
    <br>
</form>
```

That form is the only form on the page and that input box is the only form element on the page. I get this error:

```
document.forms.0.email is null or not an object
```

I've also tried changing it to `document.forms[0].elements[0].value` but I get the same type of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling it as the page renders so the element does not exist yet.

You need to have that code wrapped in some validation function that is called onsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

```
var emailRule = /^[_\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)*(\.[\D]{2,3})$/;

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        if (!emailRule.test(form.email.value)){
            window.alert("That was not a valid email address");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else
            window.alert("That was a valid email address");
    });
});
```